# Como puedo quitar parte del value a un input con js vanilla?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, eventos, input

```js
 element.addEventListener('click',function(){
                            
                            let inp = document.querySelector('#input');
                            
                            inp.value += objData[i].nombre_autor + " ";
                            
                            tesra.addEventListener('click',function(){
                                
                                inp.removeValue = objData[i].nombre_autor; 
                            });   
                        });
```

**Bueno la cosa es que esto esta dentro de un for que al seleccionar palabras quiero que se agregen en el input en el value que es un input readonly y sale bien la cosa es que despues quiero que esa palabra la ultima o cualquiera se quite si es solicitado pero no existe un removeValue asique no se como hacerlo basicamente gracias de ante mano!!**

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar un texto, se reemplaza por `''` (un string vacío).

- Para eliminar sólo la primera ocurrencia, usá [texto.replace('buscado', '')](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace)
- Para todas las ocurrencias, [texto.replaceAll('buscado', '')](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Ejemplo:

```
inp.value = inp.value.replace(objData[i].nombre_autor + ' ', '');
```